# What causes this webpack code 2 error and how to solve it?

Tags: nativescript

*Cannot even build in sidekick after a simple change*

I created a new Core/TS project in Sidekick, I built the app and developed some stuff, but later I changed the icon to a nicer one (which requires a new build, no HMR for this type of change obviously), now I cannot build my app (cloud build, because I don't have Android Studio).

I checked the /main/assets/app/ and the icons were successfully changed there and they were existed.

What is happening? How do I fix this big issue? My patience bottle with all these critical errors even after simple changes is getting *emptied*.

I also tried "removing .cloud and folder directories", and clicking "clean cloud processes", adding "clean" option, etc...
But none worked.

---

I also updated the webpack.config.js file, with node_modules.bin\update-ns-webpack --configs
The file got successfully updated, but still did *not* solve the problem and I still cannot build.

Still after many hours cannot cloud build my app in sidekick. I also tried tns platform remove android, tns install, etc, etc... none worked out.

this is the error message:

```
[00:00:18.521] [WARN]  Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
[00:00:18.681] [ERROR] clean-webpack-plugin: /mnt/storage/builds/_/af8fe992d35e76b54f5523261a83dac973ffc9ed/5.3.4/5.3.1/Spread/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/**/* has been removed.
Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
'Build failed with error code 2'.
[19-06-10 19:13:56.767] Couldn't enable debugging for EP7333JKFA, Error: Couldn't enable debugging for EP7333JKFA
    at Errors.fail (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:126:28)
    at Errors.failWithoutHelp (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:136:21)
    at LiveSyncService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\livesync\livesync-service.js:253:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\livesync\livesync-service.js:13:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\livesync\livesync-service.js:9:12)
    at LiveSyncService.enableDebuggingCoreWithoutWaitingCurrentAction (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\livesync\livesync-service.js:250:16)
    at LiveSyncService.enableDebuggingCoreWithoutWaitingCurrentAction (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\decorators.js:67:47)
    at LiveSyncService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\livesync\livesync-service.js:290:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Bridge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\livesync\livesync-service.js:10:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
OUTPUT 2
```

EDIT:
SOLVED
https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/384#issuecomment-508028462

Comment: could be a permissioning issue.

Comment: @Narendra what is "permissioning issue"? and how to solve it?

Comment: My team recently had a webpack + NativeScript issue too -- we ended up changing the devDependency in package.json to point to the release number for `nativescript-dev-webpack` (removing "next") ... `"nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.24.1"`

Comment: @Doug But I never used "next" tag in my `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer, but it is happening to me, too. I am running Nativescript 5.4.1. I can build with webpack, but as soon as I try to run with AOT or Uglify, I can't build and the error message isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and add 'nativescript-dev-webpack'-plugin using nativescript-sidekick-GUI, this resolve my issue...

Comment: I tried it many times, with deleting package-lock, platforms folder, etc... but did not work. same error

Comment: SOLVED: 
https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/384#issuecomment-508028462